# Would a HDD gain from SATA3 vs SATA2

Tags: hard-drive, sata

Since we are talking about mechanical drives that are below the 300MBps SATA2 can provide I suspect there would be no difference, but I was just wondering of other differences...

Comment: Does this answer your question?: [Can hard drives fully utilize SATA III?](https://superuser.com/q/453175/83694)

Comment: the article in one of the answers shows there is a difference between SATA2 and SATA3 besides sequential transfers, but i guess this doesnt really apply to HDDs. (I wouldnt have closed the question)